# Методы jsp страницы, переопределение init()

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Страница jsp компилируется в сервлет. У нее есть методы `jspInit()`, `jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`, `jspDestroy()`.

> Вопрос №1

Правильно я понимаю, что методы jsp - это методы сервлета, в который она компилируется?

> Вопрос №2

Как переопределить `jspInit()` на jsp странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) смотря что вы имеете в виду. Так как эти методы будут находиться внутри скомпилированного сервлета - да, это методы этого сервлета. Но если имеется в виду, является ли, например, jspInit() прямым аналогом метода init() из интерфейса Servlet, то нет, это другой метод, из интерфейса JspPage, который, в свою очередь, расширяет интерфейс Servlet и, следовательно, содержит все его методы, в том числе init().

2)
добавьте на вашу jsp скриптлет (не сработает, если скрипты в jsp запрещены)

```
<%!
public void jspInit() {
  //делайте, что хотите. Только зачем?
}
%>
```